# pyinstaller not working on linux with flask application

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I installed pyinstaller on raspberry pi(not in virtual env) successfully with `pip install pyinstaller`

`pyinstaller --version` gives me 4.6

I cd to my flask application dir and run `pyinstaller --onefile Main.py` which create build dist folder in dir and Main.spec too
but gives error and not having exe file in dist folder.

my output is

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~/BEACON/BEACON $ pyinstaller --onefile Main.py
1057 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.6
1060 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
1075 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.10.17+-armv6l-with-debian-10.8
1083 INFO: wrote /home/pi/BEACON/BEACON/Main.spec
1110 INFO: UPX is not available.
1127 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/pi/BEACON/BEACON']
4926 INFO: checking Analysis
4931 INFO: Building because Analysis-00.toc is bad
4934 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
4956 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
5228 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
92750 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
97815 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
98355 INFO: Analyzing /home/pi/BEACON/BEACON/Main.py
114833 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_find_module_path/hook-distutils.py'.
114844 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/lib/python3.7'
179158 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-six.moves.py'.
225306 INFO: Processing module hooks...
225315 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cryptography.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
229312 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks'...
229829 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
230011 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
230069 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
230120 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
231218 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
231253 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'test'
231258 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
231270 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
232883 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
244205 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/pre_safe_import_module/hook-win32com.py'.
244255 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
244260 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
244326 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks'...
245038 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
246205 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
246399 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
246466 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_inspect.py'
246503 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
247912 INFO: Including run-time hook '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
248322 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
252463 INFO: Looking for eggs
252467 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/pyinstaller", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 124, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 58, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 782, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 714, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/pi/BEACON/BEACON/Main.spec", line 19, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 155, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 501, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 605, in _check_python_library
    python_lib = bindepend.get_python_library_path()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 897, in get_python_library_path
    python_libname = findLibrary(name)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 775, in findLibrary
    lib = _which_library(name, paths)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/bindepend.py", line 806, in _which_library
    for _path in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib32'
```

what I am missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just re-Install pyinstaller. Then it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).